# Can't tell if the function is differentiable at a point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was trying to evaluate if the below function is differentiable at $(0,0),$

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \textrm{for} (x,y) \ne (0,0)\\ 0 &\textrm{at }(x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

and what I did was that I used the definition for differentiability of a function in two variables which gives,

$$f'(0,0) = \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} (-hk^2/\sqrt{h^2+k^2})$$

and here, I assumed $h = r\cos\theta$ and $k =r\sin\theta$ and limit $ r \to 0$, which gives,

$$f'(0,0) = \lim_{r\to 0} (-\sin^2\theta \cos\theta),$$

And thus, we can see that the limit is a finite value, and therefore, the limit exists, and the function is differentiable at $(0,0),$ but it is given otherwise in the answer sheet.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit has to be the same for all $\theta$ for the derivative to exist. Since the limit in this case varies with $\theta$ it follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, so it means that all the directional derivatives must exist at a point for the derivative to exist at that point.

Comment: @HasnainRaza Yes, all the directional derivatives have to exist and they have to be the same. They cannot have different values in different directions.

Answer (score 3):

You must keep in mind that, if $f'(0,0)$ exists, then it is a linear map, not a vector.

You have, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, that $f(x,0)=x$, and therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1$. By a similar argument, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. Therefore, if $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, $f'(0,0)(x,y)=x$. That means that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$In other words,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=0.$$However, this is not true, because, if $x=y>0$, $\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=1$.