# Is the function differentiable in (0,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define: $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$
$$
\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}
$$
and $f(x,y) = 0 \text{ for } (x,y) = (0,0)$

Question is the function differentiable in (0,0)?

So the definition my teacher gave me for differentiability is the following:
$f$ is differentiable in $a \in E$ with derivative $A \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ if
the following holds:
$$
r(h):=f(a+h)-f(a)-A h
$$

$$
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{r(h)}{||h||}=0
$$

I have no idea what this definition means, especially why a matrix is in the definition??

Another definition I found on the internet is:
$f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_{x}(0,0)x-f_{y}(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} = 0
$$
So using this definition: my attempt is:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} = 0
$$
this limit exists because,
$$
\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} \leq \frac{x^{3}}{x^{2}} = x < \delta = \epsilon 
$$
And this limit is $0$.

Comment: $f$ is not well-defined here, can you check the definition ?

Comment: I made a mistake in the function, I fixed it now

Comment: Maybe this one can help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021490/505767

Comment: Yes this one helped thanks, I understand that it is not differentiable at (0,0). Can we then immideatily say that the function is not a $C^{1}$ function?